# Prisma CLI detects drift with database, recommends purging all data

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, amazon-rds, prisma

I have been using Prisma (v4.12) for a few months now with a PostgreSQL database hosted at AWS RDS. I have a testing environment and a production environment. API is using NestJS.

A few days ago, we released the first version of our product in production, without issue. We have edited database production fields directly inside Prisma Data Browser.

I have been tasked to update the Prisma database schema (file `schema.prisma`). Upon running the migration (via CLI command `npx prisma migrate dev`), Prisma warns there is a drift and asks if I want to purge all data Y/n.

I have no worry about purging the testing environment database, but am worried about the migrations purging the production data. How can I prevent that ?

It does not make sense to me, which is why this issue is hard to figure out. How can I prevent any future `drift` with Prisma ?

And does Prisma only purges testing environment in order to create a safe migration file, that preserves our production environment without purging it ?

I have contacted Prisma Support about the issue. They have asked me to insert the following command in my terminal to display migration output : `npx prisma migrate diff --from-url "$YOUR_DATABASE_URL" --to-schema-datamodel "path_to_prisma_schema_file" --script > script.sql`

The script.sql file executes `DROP TABLE "table_name"`to almost all my tables.